# Django - fetching data from the different table to be shown in admin, getting the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am beginner for the Django.
I am trying to make the admin page in which I want to show the columns(**user**) from the table(**BillingProfile**) which is the foreign key to the **Order Table**.

I have created the order model as shown below.

Order Model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    billing_profile     = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, null=True, blank=True)
    order_id            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True) # AB31DE3
    shipping_address    = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="shipping_address",null=True, blank=True)
    billing_address     = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="billing_address", null=True, blank=True)
    cart                = models.ForeignKey(Cart)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id
```

The BillingProfile model is as shown below.

BillingProfile Model

```
class BillingProfile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    email       = models.EmailField()
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

And the Code for the Admin Page is as below.

admin.py

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'billing_profile','get_user']
    class Meta:
        model = Order
    def get_user(self, obj):
        return obj.billing_profile.user

admin.site.register(Order,OrderAdmin)
```

When I am trying to get the **user** of a specific **Billing profile** then I am getting the error of **'NoneType' object has no attribute user**. this might be due to the fact that few rows of Order table is empty. Can't I show the users of the remaining Rows?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is because the profile of the order is none/null, and the admin will show this error. Try:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'billing_profile','get_user']
    class Meta:
        model = Order
    def get_user(self, obj):
        return obj.billing_profile.user if obj.billing_profile else None

admin.site.register(Order,OrderAdmin)
```

Adding: *obj.billing_profile.user if obj.billing_profile else None*, that will only return the user if the obj (order) has a profile.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to modify your `get_user` method:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'billing_profile','get_user']
    class Meta:
        model = Order
    def get_user(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.billing_profile.user
        except AttributeError:
            return None
```

Comment: Can you explain what goes behind the scene, does it join the two tables or does it just retrive the data for every single row? if that is the case then it will use so much computational space.